# Cointegration tests: how do you accurately test the necessity of time trends in the Johansen and Engle-Granger tests?

Tags: time-series, stata, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

I've been testing some random prices for a study of my own and sometimes this assumption radically changes -- for instance, in Johansen tests -- from no cointegrating vectors, to the whole set of possibilities. Is there a way to implement a test adequately?

Also, what would be the restricted constant and restricted trend in the VEC model (as for the option defined in Stata)?

Edit: if one could point how to implement it in Stata, it would also be helpful.